# Weird alignment in Table

Tags: tables

For the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    Type: & A 1 & B 2 & C 3\\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Long Sentence, verryyyyy long}
\end{tabular}
```

result is:

[image]

Why A1, B2 so close and C3 left sided?

wanted something like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

assuming that `Long Sentence, verryyyyy long` is shorter than `text width ... (if it is longer, than sentence had to be broken into more lines). with use of`tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength{\tabwidth}     % for determining of table width
 \begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\settowidth\tabwidth{Long Sentence, verryyyyy long} % measurement for table width
\begin{tabularx}{\tabwidth}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    Type:   & A 1   & B 2   & C 3       \\
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Long Sentence, verryyyyy long}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```